# Invalid token error when calling Flask API for token verification

Tags: python, api, flask, microservices

Flask API returning "Invalid token" error when verifying token in the Authorization header.
I have developed a Flask API that includes token generation and verification functionality. The tokens are generated using the PyJWT library. However, when I attempt to call the /verify_token endpoint and pass the token in the Authorization header as a bearer token, the API consistently returns an "Invalid token" error

- Checked that the token is correctly included in the Authorization header as a bearer token.
- Verified that the app.config['SECRET_KEY'] is consistent when generating and verifying the token.
- Ensured that the token is not expired.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import jwt
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vmkey'  # Replace with your own secret key

@app.route('/generate_token', methods=['POST'])
def generate_token():
    client_id = request.json.get('client_id')
    client_secret = request.json.get('client_secret')

    # Check client_id and client_secret for authentication
    # Replace this with your authentication logic

    if client_id and client_secret:
        token_expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=30)  # Set token expiration time
        token = jwt.encode({'client_id': client_id, 'exp': token_expiry}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return jsonify({'token': token, 'expiry': token_expiry.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})

    return jsonify({'message': 'Authentication failed'}), 401

@app.route('/verify_token', methods=['POST'])
def verify_token():
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')

    if token:
        try:
            decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            client_id = decoded_token['client_id']
            return jsonify({'message': f'Authorization success for client ID: {client_id}'})

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token has expired'}), 401
        except (jwt.InvalidTokenError, jwt.DecodeError):
            return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid token'}), 401

    return jsonify({'message': 'No token provided'}), 401



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the text of the JWT token that you're using?

Comment: it consist of 3 part: header, payload and signature.
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiIxMjMiLCJleHAiOjE2ODUxMTY5OTQuMDIzNTY3Mn0.XDbVfheex2_y0zFRomZ0ORCogFpweQeZfTYgSXr5ijU

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons why you are getting invalid token.
However, to begin with you should verify the signature of the token, the token is always signed by a private key and verified by its public key.
This can be checked [here](https://jwt.io/)

If the you finds the signature is correct, then your should check your client configuration against which your token is getting verified, kid, client id.